# Navigating Stack Overflow Blog - Pagination?

Tags: discussion, blog

Is it an intentional design decision that there's no consistent / predictable way of navigating the articles on the Stack Overflow blog? You pretty much get what's on the home page, or whatever "related" articles the blog engine thinks are relevant when you view a particular article, but (unless I'm missing something) there doesn't seem to be (what I would consider) a traditional way to navigate sequentially through the articles (a.k.a. pagination).

For instance, if I were to read the [current article](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/26/copying-code-from-stack-overflow-you-might-be-spreading-security-vulnerabilities/) (for 2019-11-28), I'd expect to see either an "Older" / "Previous" link, or something similar, to take me to the [previous article](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/25/introducing-the-loop-a-foundation-in-listening/). Nowhere on that first article is there a link to Sara's article, nor does Sara's article contain a link to Ben Popper's article. That seems odd to me.

At the minimum, a sitemap would be great.

Comment: [I have a list](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2019/12/31/the-secret-index-of-all-stack-overflow-blog-posts/) (with some annotation).

Comment: @PeterMortensen You're officially my hero. Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We're looking at adding a link to archives and search very soon. We agree, this isn't a great feature, so we're going to improve the blog design now that we have some available resources.

Comment: Where's the correct place to make suggestions for blog design? I would like a search feature to search by title, content, author or date so I can actually find some of the more interesting ones I remember.

Comment: @Magisch [meta-tag:feature-request] [meta-tag:blog]

Comment: Looks like the blog's been redesigned. I assume I can mark this as "accepted" at this point?

Comment: @TiesonT. Yup, go for it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sitemap, [it's here](https://stackoverflow.blog/sitemap_index.xml).

If you'd read all the blogs, you'd have known where to find it, as it's [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/10/01/podcast-24/):

> Geoff discusses how important sitemap.xml was for us. Unlike a blog, we didn’t have stable, permanent links to questions. until we rolled out sitemap it was literally impossible to find questions using web search, even if you entered the exact word-for-word title. As google says, you should use sitemaps for “any site where certain pages are only accessible via a search form”.

Comment: And how does one find that article, now? There's no search, and the sitemap isn't linked from anywhere.

Comment: @TiesonT. I googled it. Just use the search operator `site:stackoverflow.blog`

Comment: Had to giggle about the answer since its implying that someone has to have read and rememberd a 11+ years old blog post to know that there is a sitemap.

Comment: @RandRandom it actually makes sense if you start at the beginning: `https://stackoverflow.blog/1`, `https://stackoverflow.blog/2`. Let me know when you've found the secret number. ;)